# Reading data from a file using Perl

Tags: perl, bioinformatics

I have used the following code in perl to open and read a file contains protein data:

```
# !/usr/bin/perl -w

$proteinFileName = 'NM_021964fragment.pep';
open (PROTEINFILE, $proteinFileName);
$protein = <PROTEINFILE>;
close PROTEINFILE;

print "Here is the protein: \n";
print "$protein";
exit;
```

The problem that I am facing is that the provided code does not print out the data.  The protein sequence data file 'NM_021964fragment.pep'  is located in my desktop and even when I specified the location it does not read the file.

Any idea to get the code running?

Comment: What do you mean when you "specified the location"? Check the return value of [`open`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfunc#open). Check the value of [`$!`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlvar#ERRNO)

Comment: I mean that giving the exact location of the file in my computer would not result in reading the file:
for example when I used this code:

    $proteinFileName = 'desktop/perl/NM_021964fragment.pep';

I hope that it is clear now

Comment: why not using the absolute whole path, for example in windows that is "c:/user/xx/desktop/perl/NM_021964fragment.pep";

Comment: It is showing that it is not able to locate the file NM_021964fragment.pep when using the whole path.  I do not know what would be the problem in this case.

Answer (score 2):

First print a diag message when open fails. This is the Perl-way to do it:

```
open PROTEINFILE, $proteinFileName or die $!;
```

Some questions:

- What is the current working directory in which you start the Perl program?
- In case of your above example, you should cd to the directory where the pep file is located.
- Do you start the script from the command line?
- Does this happen to be Cygwin-Perl on a Windows machine?

Next, the <> operator reads one line from a file.
If the file has multiple lines and you want to read the whole file into a string, you need a loop to concatenate all lines into it:

```
$protein .= $_ while (<PROTEINFILE>);
```

Comment: I think this solved part of my problem after using the code that you have provided at the beginning.  

Now, when I run the program I get an error message that shows the file is not found.  I am running perl on a Windows machine using Padre editor.  

Is there a specific way to direct my program to the file 'NM_021964fragment.pep' so it can find it and read it?  I know the file is my desktop under perl Bioinfo file.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Your `while` loop is a little overkill `my $protein;{ local $/; $protein = <PROTEINFILE> }`

Comment: @BradGilbert My overkill loop is still 10 char shorter then your solution. I'm winning in Perl golf. And it's more readable too. :-) And I can further improve my handicap: `$protein .= $_ while <PROTEINFILE>;`

Comment: @MustafaEhsan Try using the absolute path of your pep file.       `$proteinfile = 'c:\Users\<yourusername>\Desktop\NM_021964fragment.pep'` assuming Windows7.

Comment: I wasn't trying for the shortest code, I went for the **fastest** code. My code loads the **entire file** in relatively few OPs, yours requires more OPs than I used, and uses them on every line of input. Besides if I were going for a golf I would have used `$protein.=$_ for<PROTEINFILE>;`

Comment: @BradGilbert You win.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem may be caused by that your perl script is not in the same directory with you protein file. you can load two of them together and try again. if you want to input the path of file as a parameter, you can write like that below:

```
@ARGV==1 || die"please input the file path";
open(IN, $ARGV[0]) || die "can't open the file $ARGV[0]:$!";
$protein = <PROTEINFILE>; ##get one line once, if you want to get all information, use while loop or like this: @protein = <PROTEINFILE>;
##something you like to do
close(IN);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code reads first line of the file.
Use `File::Slurp` module to read whole file into variable **OR** try the code below.

```
# !/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
my $proteinFileName = 'NM_021964fragment.pep';
my $protein;
{ 
   local $/= undef;

   open (my $PROTEINFILE, '<', $proteinFileName) || die "Can't open";
   $protein = <$PROTEINFILE>;
   close $PROTEINFILE;
}

print "Here is the protein: \n";
print "$protein";
exit;
```

`man perlvar` :

> $/      The input record separator, newline by default. [...] You may set it [...] to "undef" to read through the end of file.

Comment: You need to put a `my $protein` before the block where it is set.

Comment: @BradGilbert Fixed - Thanks for spotting undesired `use strict;` consequence :-)